# Critical Error while compiling / exporting as IPA with AIR16

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air, adobe

my application crashed while compiling with AIR16. (Flex 4.13.0-AIR 16.0) 
With AIR15 it works well.

**EDIT:** Tried out AIR17beta. And who wonderes? It works!

First I thought, the reason might be the included ANE, but it isn't. The ANE works fine with another project. 
In fact other projects also work with AIR16.

The project works fine in the Simulator without any crashes or compile errors!

We've built a lot of test-apps including the same components and libraries as in this app, but we are not able to reproduce this crash in other projects.

Any ideas?

Actual Result:

**Flex 4.13.0-AIR 16.0:**

> Error occurred while packaging the application:
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: 
>   "_traits:AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6:234::Span", referenced from: 
>   _AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6:9729:Edge in AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6.o 
>   "_traits:AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6:234::Edge", referenced from: 
>   _AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6:9706:flashx.textLayout.compose::Parcel/allocateEdge
>   in AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6.o 
>   "_traits:AOTBuildOutput-0000000100_5:18::LocaleID", referenced from: 
>   _AOTBuildOutput-0000000100_5:265:mx.resources::LocaleSorter$/sortLocalesByPreference
>   in AOTBuildOutput-0000000100_5.o  ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture armv7  Compilation failed while executing : ld64

**Flex 4.14.0-AIR 16.0:**

> Error occurred while packaging the application:
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: 
>   "_traits:AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6:248::Span", referenced from: 
>   _AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6:11261:Edge in AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6_1.o 
>   "_traits:AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6:248::Edge", referenced from: 
>   _AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6:11238:flashx.textLayout.compose::Parcel/allocateEdge
>   in AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6_1.o 
>   "_traits:AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6:207::CellCoords", referenced
>   from: 
>   _AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6:8073:flashx.textLayout.elements::TableElement/normalizeCells
>   in AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6.o 
>   _AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6:8072:flashx.textLayout.elements::TableElement/getBlockedCoor
>   ds in AOTBuildOutput-0000000101_6.o 
>   "_traits:AOTBuildOutput-0000000100_5:18::LocaleID", referenced from: 
>   _AOTBuildOutput-0000000100_5:340:mx.resources::LocaleSorter$/sortLocalesByPreference
>   in AOTBuildOutput-0000000100_5.o  ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture armv7  Compilation failed while executing : ld64

Comment: We just tested an *.apk export. works also fine!

Comment: I think you have to check `<option>` in your `platformOptions.xml` file

Comment: @ketan: would you please provide me, how to use the platformOptions.xml !?

I tried adding "-platformoptions /path/to/platformoptions.xml" before -keystore option.

Comment: I think you have look http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html which gives step by step proper description

Comment: @ketan: i am **not** building a native extension.

Comment: Tried out AIR17beta. And who wonderes? It works!